# Upper bounding the variance of a sum

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds

I have random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_N$ and two functions: a bounded function $|f|\leq M$ and another function $0 \le g \le 1$. I would like to upper bound the variance
$$
\mathbb{V}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N f(X_i)g(X_i) \right]
$$
by a bound that does not depend on $f$ (happy for it to depend on $g$). Is it possible?

## Attempt

I tried by using the usual variance formula, but I am unsure if I can do this type of bounds
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{V}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N f(X_i)g(X_i) \right]
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^N f(X_i)g(X_i)\right)^2\right] - \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N f(X_i)g(X_i)\right]^2 \\
&\leq \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^N M g(X_i)\right)^2\right]- \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N f(X_i)g(X_i)\right]^2 \\
&= M^2 \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^N g(X_i)\right)^2\right] - \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N f(X_i)g(X_i)\right]^2 \\
&\leq M^2 \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^N g(X_i)\right)^2\right]
\end{align}
$$
but I was wondering if I can do anything better. One idea I had was to work directly on the formula for the variance of a sum
$$
\mathbb{V}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N f(X_i)g(X_i)\right] = \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{V}[f(X_i)g(X_i)] + 2 \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=i+1}^N \text{Cov}\left(f(X_i)g(X_i), f(X_j)g(X_j)\right)
$$

Comment: That inequality isn't valid as written (what if $\sum g(X_i) = 0$?); you'd need $\sum M|g(X_i)|$ instead.

Comment: @GregMartin Mmmm I think I forgot to write a condition. Here I know that $g$ is non-negative as well

Comment: $(X_n)_{n=1,..,N}$ are i.i.d?

Comment: @NN2 Yes, they are! $X_1, \ldots X_n \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \mu$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the assumption that $(X_i)_{i=1,..,N}$ are i.i.d, we deduce that  $(f(X_i)g(X_i))_{i=1,..,N}$ are also i.i.d. As a consequence
$$\begin{align}
L:=\mathbb{V}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N f(X_i)g(X_i) \right) &= n\cdot \mathbb{V}\left( f(X_1)g(X_1) \right) \\
&= n\cdot \mathbb{E}\left(f^2(X_1)g^2(X_1) \right)-n\cdot \mathbb{E}^2\left(f(X_1)g(X_1) \right)\\
\end{align}$$
Without any further information about $f,g$ and $X$, a best upper bound is
$$L\stackrel{(1)}{\le}n\cdot \mathbb{E}\left(f^2(X_1)g^2(X_1) \right)\stackrel{(2)}{\le}\color{red}{nM^2\cdot \mathbb{E}\left(g^2(X_1) \right)}$$
The equality of $(1)$ occurs if for example $f$ is an odd function, $g$ is an even function and $X$ follows a symmetric distribution.

The equality of $(2)$ occurs if and only if $|f(x)| = M$ for all $x$.